# Title for sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a file with many sql queries and I'd like to give each of these queries a title, so when I execute them I can identify every query in the "Messages" box.

By now I'm using just a print, but it's a bit messy because it is placed just after the results of the previous query.

**PSEUDO.sql**

```
print 'query label 1'
<query1>
go

print 'query label 2'
<query2>
go
```

**Executing PSEUDO.sql**

```
Messages:

query label 1

(Rows affected: 3)
query label 2

(Rows affected: 5)
```

Do you know if there is a method to have somehting like

```
query label 1
(Rows affected: 3)

query label 2
(Rows affected: 5)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for this: [Is there any way to stop the extra new line after a print statement in t-sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606084/is-there-any-way-to-stop-the-extra-new-line-after-a-print-statement-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

USE `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON  

print 'query label 1'
<query1>
PRINT '(Rows affected:'+CAST(@@ROWCOUNT as VARCHAR(10))+')'

print 'query label 2'
<query2>
PRINT '(Rows affected:'+CAST(@@ROWCOUNT as VARCHAR(10))+')'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a variable using  "declare@variable" give it a default value and execute the variable with your query

may it can help you.